# Make use of variables in chef inspec

Tags: inspec

Is it possible to make use of environment variable and even concatenating it for describe and match? Below is an example

**files.rb**

```
title "File section"

django_project = os_env("DJANGO_PROJECT")

control "files.1" do
    title "Django Settings Configuration"
    desc "Django Settings Boilerplate must be followed"
    describe file(django_project + "/setting.py") do
        it { should exist }
        it { should be_file}
    end
end
```